# CSS Centering problems of a 500px div

Tags: css, widget, width, centering

I have a classs for a widget area and I have tried every CSS centering technique I know.....and more.

I've had the most success with:

```
.widget {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

However it doesn't work on a variety of screen widths.

Any pointer would be appreciated as I'd love to brush up on my CSS centering.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your whole structure looks like, but if that works, I would recommend just doing:

```
.widget {
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 250px);
}
```

Note that this is keeping the widget with a fixed width of 500px (not max-width)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change both:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

and a fiddle to demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0zgrf49j/

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a specific answer without the rest of the code, but this is a popular technique:

```
.widget {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```